# How to Format Export Excel Sheet using Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, xlsx, exceljs, filesaver.js

Need to export json data to the excel file(large data), I can able to download the file and need to do some styles to the excel file(font, color, headers). I tried `file-saver`, Could you please suggest how to format the excel file.

```
loadData() {
    const dataUrl =
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json';
    this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(response => {
      this.data = response.data;
    });
  }

  exportAsXLSX(): void {
    this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.data, 'PersonsData');
  }
```

[Export to excel](https://stackblitz.com/edit/export-to-excel-angular-api-data)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [SheetJS](https://sheetjs.com/pro) package you are using only offers style features in the PRO version. You cannot add a style without having the [PRO](https://sheetjs.com/pro) version.